# how can angular ui modal popup from right side

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

how can the angular ui modal popup from right side, not the top ? That will be more interesting.
[angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: I prefer to have a settings to change it.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'windowClass' parameter.

eg:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'modal-template.html',
            size: 'lg',
            windowClass: 'right',
            resolve: {}
        });
```